# how to hot reload sass in webpack?

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack

Any body know that config the webpack file to hot reload the sass file ?
here is my webpack.config file and it just support the html and javascript hot reload.I am eager to use sass hot reload ! help!help!

here is my webpack.config

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/main.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/build/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,

            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=8192',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            },
            { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css'),
            sass: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./app.css'),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ],
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var open = require('open')
var DEV_PORT = 8080

var config = require('./webpack.config.js')
var myConfig = Object.create(config)
var webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var webpack = require('webpack')
myConfig.entry.unshift('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/','webpack/hot/dev-server')
new webpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
    noInfo: false,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: false,
    publicPath: myConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    proxy: {
        '/admin/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000'
        },

    }
}).listen(DEV_PORT, "localhost", err => {
})
app.listen(5010, function() {
    console.log('waitint ....')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the ExtractTextPlugin.  No hot module replacement is listed as a disadvantage of it in the docs: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: It should suffice to configure `{disable: true}` for `ExtractTextPlugin` during development. That way you can keep the loader configuration.